# Python: Multiple File Classes

Tags: python

I'm wondering how you can get classes that are split up between files to edit variables in my main game loop.

For example here is a extremely basic version of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Player class:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, field):
        self.name = name
        self.field = field
        self.health = 500
    def summon(self,card):
        self.field.summon(card)
```

Field Class:

```
class Field():
    def __init__(self):
        self.playing_field = []
    def summon(self, card):
        self.playing_field.append(card)
        player1.health = 400
```

And my game file:

```
from Player import Player
from Field import Field

player1_field = Field()
player1 = Player("Steve", player1_field)

test_card = ["Test Card", 300] # Name, Power
player1.summon(test_card)
```

This raises the error:

```
NameError: global name 'player1' is not defined
```

I've gotten to a point in my game where I need classes to be split up between files but I'm having trouble with making them talk to each other. I'm wondering how I can declare my player objects so that they can be accessed from all of my classes, which is becoming a long list.

If you need me to edit this question please say so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not good class design. You've permanently tied `Field` to a single instance of `Player`. Why not let `Field` take the player as a variable, e.g. `Field.add_player`?

Comment: Your problem is not the concept of import but the question about a reasonable OO design and implementation. You are programming something together in the hope that it just works without having a reasonable idea about what you are doing. Not trying to understand what you are trying to do but setting player1.health = 400 inside a class method is bare nonsense.

Comment: I definitely didn't think very well when constructing this, I'm quite new to programming so I'm sorry if this seems like a waste of your time. My aim is to have 2+ players, all having an associated instance of a Field class, and a UsedCard class etc. I was wanting to be able to call a method of an instance of Player, such as the player1 variable. The health thing was just to demonstrate that I didn't know how to call anything of player1's methods or setter methods(I think that is the name) My real use for this is where I have an Input Handler class which needs to call methods of player1 or 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you're trying to do, **avoid accessing globals altogether.** You don't need them, and they get in the way of working out the right design.

In OO design, objects manipulate themselves or other objects. If you want `Field` to manipulate `Player`, pass the player either as an argument of `summon()`, or as an argument of the constructor for `Field`. It depends on the logic of what you're trying to model: If you can summon various players to the field, pass the player as an argument of `summon()`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me in terms of my grasp on OO design. Is there a way for me to message you in private more? Just so I know I'm on the write track in terms of my design?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have that kind of time. Plenty of others on SO are willing to help, though, if you put some thought into the questions you formulate.

Answer (score 0):

In the future I would provide the full traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stuff.py", line 8, in <module>
    player1.summon(test_card)
  File "/Users/jvanvoorst/blah2/Player.py", line 7, in summon
    self.field.summon(card)
  File "/Users/jvanvoorst/blah2/Field.py", line 6, in summon
    player1.health = 400
```

The problem is the Field class member function summon doesn't know anything about player1.

You need to either pass in a reference to the player or add the player to the Field class.  How to best design this depends on how many fields there are, can multiple players use the same field, etc.